# How can we update the App Engine Java SDK Using the New Google Cloud Plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have recently updated from the deprecated [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) to the new [Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart).

[image: Eclipse - Add Library]

After adding in the "Web App Libraries" through the "Add Library" section (shown above), I can see when expanding (see below) that I've imported older versions of the Google App Engine SDK for Java, version 1.9.48.  The current version at the time of this post is 1.9.57, available on the [App Engine SDK for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download) page.

[image: Eclipse Java Build Path image]

But there's nothing about where to place this update so it's recognized. I already have 1.9.51 on my computer, but the plugin is using 1.9.48 only.

How can we update Eclipse so "Web App Libraries" imports the latest App Engine SDK?  This used to be much easier with the old deprecated plugin, as we could import the SDK bundle via the "Google" menu.

Answer (score 0):

Importing libraries does not seem to be the preferred way to install the SDK. It is more effective to follow the instructions in the "[Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart)" for Eclipse, namely:

1) Install Eclipse IDE 4.5 or later:

2) Install the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK:

3) Run the following command to add the gcloud component that includes the App Engine SDK for Java:

gcloud components install app-engine-java

Answer (score 0):

Preferences-->Google--> Appengine

choose your Sdk,by defaults the choosed one will be added to the build path of any new project

Answer (score 0):

My project somehow got locked to a particular version.  To fix it:

Windows -> Preferences -> Google Cloud Tools -> Untick "Choose SDK".

[image]